# Mirroring a WebDAV directory for backups

Tags: linux, open-source, webdav

I want to mirror a webdav directory to have local backups of it. Currently, I use

```
rm *
lftp <<__END__
open -u USER,PW https://example.com/remote.php/caldav/calendars/USER/kalender
mget /remote.php/caldav/calendars/USER/kalender/*.ics .
__END__
```

but re-downloading everything repeatedly is annoying.

What would be a suitable tool that mirrors a remote WebDAV directory to a local directory, including deleting removed files and adding new ones? (Should run on Linux and be Free Software.)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is mount the webdav directory using something like [davfs](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/davfs2) and than use rsync to regularly sync your mirror directory.

Comment: Looked at `davfs2`, but I dislike that mounts have to be present in `/etc/fstab` or done by root.

Comment: Try one of the alternatives? [fusedav](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/fusedav/) or [wdfs](http://noedler.de/projekte/wdfs/)

Comment: fusedav fails here (`PROPFIND failed: 404 Not Found`); wdfs seems to be not packages; I think I’ll look at it another time.

Answer (score 0):

lftp supports "mirror", have you tried that?

Otherwise there is a tool for this: http://www.re.be/webdav_sync/index.xhtml